# Singleton without copy constructor

Tags: c++, singleton

I am viewing a source code and it has got a singleton class like :

```
class A {
    private:
     A() {}
     ~A() {}
};
```

And i see no copy constructor and assignment operator. When i talked about it, i got the response that it would not fail.

But i had read that making copy constructor and assignment operator private or inaccessible is important. But i am unable to generate some breaking test cases.

What test case can create two objects of this class ?

Comment: `A* x = new A(getA()); A* y = new A(*x); A* z = new A(*y); // who cares if it leaks, we're proving the code broken anyway...` It sounds like the person that gave you the response doesn't know C++. You should buy them a [book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes that wouldn't work, the destructor is private and those are automatic variables.

Comment: @Luchian good point. Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you can get a hold of an instance of `A`, you could copy it with

```
A* a = new A(instance);
```

An automatic variable wouldn't work because of the private destructor.

Comment: can you explain "automatic variable" ?

Comment: @AshishNegi a variable in automatic storage (stack).